# Announcments Control in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

What is the recommended way to implement an announcments (or news) control in WPF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is just to use a `ListBox` control and style it accordingly. If you don't want items to be selectable, then a vertical `StackPanel` would probably do the job. The beauty of WPF is that this using any control of the right form as your base still provides a high enough degree of flexibility/customisation to get you *exactly* what you want with minimal effort.